# Message metric without topic name

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, jmx-exporter

I am pulling metric below into Prometheus to get information about messages sent to Kafka brokers. I am seeing that some of them coming without topic. I am wondering what type of messages they are? I would expect only messages sent to specific topic.

```
kafka_server_brokertopicmetrics_messagesin_total{instance="broker:9999",job="kafka"}
kafka_server_brokertopicmetrics_messagesin_total{instance="broker:9999",job="kafka",topic="TopicEvent"}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't use the Kafka JMX Exporter, but the top seems to be all messages in to that broker. The bottom seems to be for a specific topic.

Comment: Yeah :)Thanks man